# Searching for X but not Y in ed

Tags: regular-expression, ed

In the editor sam, one can search for and print out the string "ed" but not "red" with this command:

```
,x./*\n/ g/ed v/red p
```

I was trying to find a way to do something similar in ed. I want to search for the string "ed" but not get lines with:

r*ed*, lov*ed*, load*ed*, etc.

I am familiar with the v command but not sure how to combine this with a g command, or if it is possible in ed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is better done with a regular expression that includes word boundary markers:

```
g/\<ed\>/p
```

Note that I'm not entirely familiar with `sam` so I can't comment on the editing expression that you're showing.  The expression above would print each *line* containing the *word* `ed`, i.e. the string `ed` preceded and followed by something other than a *word character*.  A word character is a character from the set `[[:alnum:]_]`.  The `\<` and `\>` are zero-width assertions, and will match at the border between word characters and non-word characters.

The `\<` and `\>` are non-standard, but available on GNU systems, and on some BSD systems.  macOS uses `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` instead while GNU systems additionally may use `\b` both at the start and end of a word to match.

If you want to do this portably, you will have to match `[^[:alnum:]_]ed[^[:alnum:]_]` but also remember to account for the special cases where the word occurs at the very start or end of a line, or where `ed` are the only two characters on a line.

Comment: I can confirm that this solution works on Gnu ed 1.18-pre2, and on the ed that comes shipped with Solaris, but not on the Plan9 ed which I am using. It appears then that older Unix versions of ed do not support zero-width assertions. I wonder then how this effect is achieved in these older versions.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an extension to Kusalananda's answer, Ex is also an POSIX editor and [POSIX does require it to support the `\< \>` word anchors](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html#tag_20_40_13_58). So I suggest just using

```
g/\<ed\>/p
```

but in Ex.